# Printing results in pandas after a "contains" string search?

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas, so I quickly ran into a problem. I'm currently using Spyder.

I'm trying to find a phrase (not the full string) in a column and pull out all the rows that contain that phrase. Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:\...\Desktop\publiccomments.csv")
print[df2["Document_Title"].str.contains("King")]
```

When I do this, I get a Boolean list:

```
    0         True
    1        False
    2        False
    3        False
    4        False
```

&tc.

When I tried to mask it, I got a whole host of errors.

```
print(df2["Document_Title"].str.contains("King"))
```

returned

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:...Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-                          packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
          execfile(filename, namespace)
        File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
          exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
        File "C:/Users/.../untitled1.py", line 15, in <module>
          print(df2[df2["Document_Title"].str.contains("King")])
        File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2053, in __getitem__
          return self._getitem_array(key)
        File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2080, in _getitem_array
          if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
        File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 201, in is_bool_indexer
          raise ValueError('cannot index with vector containing '
      ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

I tried adding

```
df2 = df1.dropna(subset=df1.columns[[1]], how='any')
```

To address the "cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values" error, but no dice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's a sample of my data:

```
                                    Document_Title       Document Type  \
0                      Comment submitted by J. King  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
1                     Comment submitted by N. Ghani  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
2                   Comment submitted by M. Srobode  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
3                     Comment submitted by D. Hovey  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
4                  Comment submitted by B. Sweigert  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
5                   Comment submitted by M. Lundgen  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
6  Comment submitted by Craig (no surname provided)  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
7                  Comment submitted by R. Marshall  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
8                     Comment submitted by A. Greig  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   
9               Comment submitted by J. B. Anderson  PUBLIC SUBMISSIONS   

  Posted Date Received Date Comment Start Date Comment Due Date  \
0  10/16/2014      9/8/2014          6/18/2014        12/1/2014   
1    8/6/2014      6/7/2014          6/18/2014       10/16/2014   
2  10/16/2014     9/15/2014          6/18/2014        12/1/2014   
3    8/6/2014      6/7/2014          6/18/2014       10/16/2014   
4  12/18/2014     11/8/2014          6/18/2014        12/1/2014   
5  10/16/2014     9/15/2014          6/18/2014        12/1/2014   
6    8/6/2014      6/7/2014          6/18/2014       10/16/2014   
7   8/15/2014      6/7/2014          6/18/2014       10/16/2014   
8  12/18/2014     11/8/2014          6/18/2014        12/1/2014   
9  10/16/2014     9/15/2014          6/18/2014        12/1/2014   

                                 Document Detail  
0  [hyperlink] 
1  [hyperlink]  
2  [hyperlink]  
3  [hyperlink]   
4  [hyperlink]  
6  [hyperlink]  
7  [hyperlink] 
8  [hyperlink]  
9  [hyperlink]
```

Comment: It's your data.  And you haven't shown us it.  Do that and you'll get lot's more help.

Comment: What's the best way to show the data?

Comment: depends on how big.  But try `print(df1.head(40))` and [edit] your post and copy/paste.  Or even more convenient `df1.head(40).to_clipboard()`  then paste into your post.

Comment: Just added some of it, thanks!

Comment: On that data, the suggested solutions and your attempt work.  So this data is not sufficient to find the problem.  I suspect you have a null in your index.  Try `df1[df1.index.notna()].pipe(lambda d: d[d["Document_Title"].str.contains("King")]])`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this

```
df2 = df[df["Column"].str.contains("King")]
print(df2)
```

Basically what you're doing in your code is retrieving a Boolean series on the condition. If you use that one to filter your data file (i.e. pass it as selecting rows of the data frame, as in the code), it does what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work--I got an error message that looks pretty similar to the one I posted.

Comment: Hey, it works even with missing values for me, so that seems not to be the problem. Unless you provide more details, it's impossible to help unfortunately....:)

Answer (score -1):

I think your df2 is screwy somehow. Here's an example df:

```
title   tractsOfLand
King    100
Duke    50
Dutchess    4
Baron   5
Princess    5000
Rey 90
Roi 23
```

Make a boolean mask and index the df with it:

```
m = df2["title"].str.contains("King")
df2[m]
```

Gives:

```
title  tractsOfLand
King           100
```

Take a look at boolean indexing [in the cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html?highlight=boolean%20indexing#boolean-indexing).

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately! I got another error message that looks pretty similar to the first.